# What is the meaning behind the deleted ending scene in "The Shining"?

Tags: plot-explanation, alternate-version, the-shining

Stanley Kubrick cut a scene at the end of *The Shining* (1980).

In that scene, we would see that Mr. Ullman visits Danny and Wendy Torrance at the hospital where they are recovering from shock. He says to Wendy that the police didn't find any evidence of anything at all out of the ordinary.

Then, he walks out of Wendy's room and gives Danny a yellow ball.

The yellow ball that Ullman gives to Danny seems to be a link to the scene when Danny goes into Room 237 (after he's playing on the rug and [a yellow ball rolls toward him](https://youtu.be/S6bZzFlj35s?si=F1bs6Cz6jSyWAZXV)).

So, what meanings can that scene hide? Can it explain the presence of Jack Torrance in the old picture of Overlook, something like that Jack is absorbed by the Hotel?

The reason for that cutting is explained and the images of the screenplay are [here](http://www.theoverlookhotel.com/post/41259062113/screenplay-for-the-deleted-original-ending-of-the).

Comment: It’s the same ball that Jack is bouncing [in front of the staircase](https://youtu.be/ErWIPb9qYAk?si=jdkg4zKcoe2nUKtA).  

Also, the name of the room with the bar is [“The Ball Room”](https://youtu.be/AmcnnRv58Z4?si=Rr3vCpjzaUdsg1xk).

Answer (score 2):

I'd interpret this scene as Ullman acting as an agent of the Overlook hotel in order to get Danny back.

The whole *Shining* - both the book and the movie - is about the evil hotel trying to use the supernatural qualities of Danny - something that Hallorann called "shining" - in order to multiply its own powers of evil.

Now that Danny (and his mother) got away, I believe in this scene Ullman has been sent by the Hotel to bring Danny back. He appears to want to take care of Danny and his mom, lies about the investigation not finding anything unusual (to convince them there's nothing to be afraid in the hotel itself, that everything that happened was just Jack's madness) and ultimately plans to bring the boy back.

Not right away of course - first to take care of them in the LA house, and later maybe separate Danny from Wendy, maybe kidnap him, anyway somehow get him back to Overlook so the Hotel can use his powers to the fullest.

And the yellow ball - what the hotel first used to draw Danny to the room 237 - is just a symbol of that.

I don't think it has anything to do with Jack appearing in the old photo, seeing as that was not cut from the movie, while the hospital scene was.